# Improving and optimizing squeeze() function

Tags: optimization, c, strings

I am currently reading *The C Programming Language* by Dennis Richie and Brian Kernighan, and I came to implement the function `squeeze (s1, s2)` as an exercise. `squeeze()` deletes each character in `s1` that matches any character in the string `s2`. While coding `squeeze()`, I thought that I can extend its capability to act like `trim()` method in Java, and then the my code was already done, and tested.

However, even though it is implemented in C, I believe that the code below can be improved and optimized. Please help me do so.

```
char *squeeze (char *str1, char *str2) {

     int i, j;
     int str1Len = strlen (str1);
     int toBeSubtractLen = 0; 

     char chr1 = '\0';
     char chr2 = '\0';

     for (i = 0; i < str1Len; i++) {
          chr1 = str1 [i];
          for (j = 0; j < strlen (str2); j++) {
               chr2 = str2 [j];
               if (chr1 == chr2) {
                    toBeSubtractLen++;     
               }               
          }
     }

     char *finalStr;
     finalStr = malloc ((str1Len - toBeSubtractLen) + 1);
     if (finalStr == NULL) {
          printf ("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
          exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     int indx = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < str1Len; i++) {
          chr1 = str1 [i];
          for (j = 0; j < strlen (str2); j++) {
               chr2 = str2 [j];
               if (chr1 == chr2) {
                    break;
               }
          }
          if (chr1 != chr2) {
               finalStr[indx] = chr1;
               indx++;
          }
     }
     return finalStr;

} /* end of squeeze() */
```

Samples:

1. str1 = ",AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmAaAaAaNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"
2. str2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
3. str3 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
4. name = "ChristopherM.Sawi"
5. birthday = "August14,1988"

Outputs:

> ```
> 1. squeeze-ing str1 by str2 yields: "<space>,<tab>abcdefghijklmaaanopqrstuvwxyz"
> 2. squeeze-ing str1 by str3 yields: "<space>m<tab>ABCDEFGHIJKLMAAANOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
> 3. squeeze-ing str2 by str3 yields: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
> 4. squeeze-ing name by str3 yields: "C<space>M.<space>S"
> 5. squeeze-ing birthday by str1 yields: "141988"
> ```

Comment: Output 2 starts with a ',' not an 'm'

Answer (score 6):

You want to avoid repeat iteration over the 2nd string, which is O(N).  Do this N times and you have an O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

One trick you could use is to build a lookup table of the chars in `str2`.  This would cost O(N) and some extra memory upfront, but then subsequent lookups in the table could be brought down to O(1).

Here's a simple example.  The trade-off is this takes a bit more memory and makes some assumptions about the range of `char`.  It also clobbers the buffer of `str1`:

```
#include <limits.h>   // for UCHAR_MAX

char *squeeze (char *str1, char *str2)
{
   char present[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
   char *src, *dst;

   // Build lookup table of chars in str2
   //
   while (*str2)
      present[(unsigned char)*str2++] = 1;

   // Iterate through str1, removing chars along the way.
   //
   src = dst = str1;
   while (*src)
   {
      // Is *src in str2?
      //
      if (present[(unsigned char)*src])
      {
         // Yes, remove this char.. (Advance src but not dst.)
         //
         ++src;
      }
      else
         *dst++ = *src++;
   }

   // NUL terminator
   //
   *dst = 0;

   return str1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Minor improvements:

- `chr1` and `chr2` are initialized to `'\0'` before being assigned, but they will always be reassigned before being read. `i` and `j` are not being initialized, but, similarly, will be assigned before being read. If you're going for performance optimization, consider leaving `chr1` and `chr2` uninitialized. If you're going for good programming practice, consider initializing `i` and `j`.
- The loops `for (j = 0; j < strlen (str2); j++)` call `strlen` each iteration even though `str2` doesn't change anywhere in the function. Consider creating a `str2len` variable like `str1len` to remove the unnecessary calls.

Major improvement:

- The first loop isn't necessary. It's only purpose is to determine the length of `finalStr`, but we know that a) `squeeze` never returns a string longer than `str1`, and b) `indx` contains the actual length of `finalStr`. Knowing this, you can `malloc` `finalStr` to the size of `str1 + 1`, then `realloc` it to `indx + 1` before returning.

---

*Edit:* `finalStr` needs to have a trailing `\0` assigned to it before returning, also. Consider setting it before returning or by calling `memset` after `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by @asveikau is more efficient, but here is a small version, for what it is worth. Note that I have used the standard library `strchr` to look for chars within strings. This is better than rolling your own loop to do the same thing and also avoids nested loops (always a bad sign).

```
#include <string.h>
char *
squeeze(char *s, const char *t)
{
    char *out = s;

    for (int i=0; s[i]; ++i) {
        if (!strchr(t, s[i]))
            *out++ = s[i];
    }
    *out = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to iterate over both the strings only once. Create a third temporary variable, equal to size of first string, and copy characters one-by-one if no match is found in the second string.

```
char *squeeze (char *destination, char *source) {

    char * result = (char*) malloc (destination_length + 1);
    bool found = FALSE;

    int destination_length = strlen (destination);
    int source_length = strlen (source);
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < destination_length; i++) {
        found = FALSE;
        for (int j = 0; j < source_lenth; j++) {
            if ( source [j] == destination [i] ) {
                found = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( FALSE == found ) {
            result [k++] = destination[i];
        }
    }

    destination [k] = '\0';
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, however I think you've actually described more or less the same algorithm @chrismsawl is using.  Specifically this "if no match is found in the second string" part - implemented naively that would be another traversal of `str2` at each step.  Can you share more details of how you'd do it?